# How can I inject a Terraform resource into my Lambda code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-sns

I've got a Terraform file that creates an AWS Lambda and an AWS SNS Topic. The lambda sends a message to the SNS topic. At the moment I have hardcoded the ARN for the SNS Topic in the lambda. Is there anyway of getting the lambda to pickup the ARN from Terraform instead?

Answer (score 1):

I would create an environment variable for your lambda containing the ARN of your SNS topic. Then lambda function can read that variable and use it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that might help you or give you an idea, but SQS is also used in that Terraform.

```html
#resources.tf

resource "aws_sns_topic" "results_updates" {
    name = "results-updates-topic"
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "results_updates_queue" {
    name = "results-updates-queue"
    redrive_policy  = "{\"deadLetterTargetArn\":\"${aws_sqs_queue.results_updates_dl_queue.arn}\",\"maxReceiveCount\":5}"
    visibility_timeout_seconds = 300

    tags = {
        Environment = "dev"
    }
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "results_updates_dl_queue" {
    name = "results-updates-dl-queue"
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "results_updates_sqs_target" {
    topic_arn = "${aws_sns_topic.results_updates.arn}"
    protocol  = "sqs"
    endpoint  = "${aws_sqs_queue.results_updates_queue.arn}"
}
```

Hope this helps
:)